# Setting select box using jQuery on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, frameworks, css-selectors

Can anyone suggest how I get to change the selected item in a select menu with jQuery - I've tried the following but without success. Using this snippet how would I use jQuery to set to value '5' for example (eg Cambridgeshire) as the 'selected' value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#county_id option[value=3]').attr('selected', 'selected');
});

<html>
<select name="county_id" id="county_id">
<option value="1">Bedfordshire</option>
<option value="2">Berkshire</option>
<option value="4">Buckinghamshire</option>
<option value="5">Cambridgeshire</option>
</select>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$('#county_id').val(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in most cases and will automatically select the correct option.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#county_id').val(3);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use a jquery selector than edit the attributes.

```
 $('input:radio[name=county_id]')[3].checked = true;
```

or

```
 $('input:radio[name=county_id]:nth(3)').attr('checked',true);
```

In this case, 3 is the counter associated with Cambridgeshire (remember, counting starts at zero).

[via](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-select-a-radio-button-with-jquery/)